# Toggling location updates from intentservice

Tags: android, gps, intentservice, looper

I have code which is checking the database if the user wants to have the GPS running. I need to run through this every couples of minutes can I am using a Intentservice to run run the method. I've tried implementing Looper but that ends up with the code never running the check again. Without the Looper I get the Looper error that I cannot create a handler in thread that has not called Looper.prepare();

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask gpsTask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gpsPlotter();
    }
};

// schedule the task to run starting now and then every hour...
timer.schedule(gpsTask, 0, 200);


private void gpsPlotter(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                BeaconHandler dbg = new BeaconHandler(Ping.this);
                List<Beacon> beacons = dbg.getAllBeacons();
                int activecheck = 0;
                for(Beacon bn : beacons){
                    activecheck = activecheck + bn.getStatus();
                }
                //db.close();
                if(activecheck > 0 && updateset == 0){
                    pinger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, reciever);
                    updateset = 1;
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Set");
                }
                else if(activecheck == 0 && updateset == 1){
                    pinger.removeUpdates(reciever);
                    updateset = 0;
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "Listener Removed");
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("GPS RESET", "No Modifications");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("GPS RESET ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. When I start request location updates I needed to register it like so.

```
pinger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 10, reciever, getMainLooper());
```